# Function return in nested object

Tags: javascript

This is normal look for my code. This is simple resource used later in canvas and this works.

```js
var myObject = {
 resourceAnim: new Resource("images/loop-images/", 20, true),
}
```

Now I need to check `somevar` and make logic branch.

```
var myObject = 
  resourceLoop: () => {
    if (somevar == 0) {
      return new Resource("images/loop-images/", 20, true),
    } else {
      return new Resource("images/loop-images/", 50, true),
    }
  }

}
```

But this is not the same. Any suggestion for nested object structure?

Comment: It depends on when you need to check `somevar`.  Do you want to check it immediately when defining `myObject`, or do you want to check it later when referencing `resourceLoop`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use a ternary operator?

```
var myObject = {
  resourceLoop: somevar == 0 ? new Resource("images/loop-images/", 20, true) : new Resource("images/loop-images/", 20, true),
}
```

Comment: Nice, i run from `ternary operator` i always use if/else but in this case i understand it now!